# Data modeling, how to model such a structure into classes?

Tags: javascript, java, entity, data-modeling

I've a Book class

```
Class Book
{
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

which has some general properties and some other Libraries specific properties, so book id '111' in library "xyz" has title property and in library "abc" has numberOfPages and dimensions
so, It will look like:

```
Class Book
{
    String name;
    String id;
    String xyzTitle;
    int abcNumberOfPages;
    float abcHeight;
    float abcWidth;
}
```

BUT this doesn't look good. why not create a separate classes for book info

```
Class XYZBookInfo
{
   String title;
}

Class ABCBookInfo
{
   int numberOfPages;
   float height;
   float width;
}

Class Book
{
   String name;
   String id;
   XYZBookInfo xyzInfo;
   ABCBookInfo abcInfo;
}
```

So good so far, But; what if a couple of libraries share some properties!
if XYZ and ABC library are interested in **Book's weight** but another library ZZZ isn't?

Where to add weight property? 
even if we create a class WeightedBookInfo then create subclasses XYZBookInfo and ABCBookInfo from it, then we will have to duplicate weight value in both class' instances??!!

I'm trying to create a xcode core data model to represent this structure, but it doesn't matter, it's a concept related question not technology specific.

Comment: If we're talking conceptually, I don't do data modeling with OOP classes.  In my database, I would include all attributes required by all users of the database, in a well-normalized schema.  In my application, an object that deals with book data would query for the attributes it requires.  ABC, XYZ and ZZZ might be instances of different classes, it's hard to say without knowing what they and related components are supposed to do.

Comment: I don't care with the storage, I'm just building the model into entity classes in my application. ABC, XYZ and ZZZ are libraries who sells books, but they don't share book attributes and some of them care about attributes other libraries don't, some attributes are shared between some of them but no the others!
so I suggest making new ABCInfo, XYZInfo and ZZZInfo classes so every library-specific attribute will be in a separate library-spcific info class. To separate libraries info from the libraries info!

Comment: If ABC, XYZ and ZZZ were instances of different classes, they could have different nested Book classes with the appropriate attributes.

Comment: This is not the case, I've only one book instance for a book, and this book '111' has XYZInfo and ABCInfo and maybe no ZZZInfo.

Comment: I'm trying to separate concerns between classes. for example if at any point of time if XYZ suddenly provided an API to provide different values for different attributes, like a discount changing every day. so I will just write a couple of functions in the XYZInfo to call the API and get the new values, and ABC values are changing every day, and a user needs to manually change in some kind of UI forms in app or something, and ZZZ are changing with a different method!
if all props are in one class, I'll need to check if this book is being sold by which lib and apply different change functions!

Comment: I wouldn't put library behaviour like discount decisions into a book class.  I would design books as data to be passed between the objects in the system, not as active components by themselves.

Comment: Exactly, that's the point. I want to separate books' library-specific behavior  into separate classes. but I'm confused about the relations! to be more specific, the shared books' behavior-properties between different libraries

Comment: Do books behave differently in real libraries?  No, books just sit there or get passed around, it's libraries that behave differently.  I can't help you fix your model, it doesn't make sense to me, so I advise a completely different way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85319/discussion-between-amtourky-and-reaanb).

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate out the intellectual content from the representation or you'll severely limit the usefulness.  Also, make use of generalization for the physical properties.  So maybe:

A class for book with properties such as title and author).  (This class may inherit from publication or something.)

An interface for bookEdition that would have ISBN, date, publisher, format (paperback, hardcover, mobi, pdf, etc.)

An interface for physicalPublication that would have numberOfPages

Some kind of interface for physical thing that has dimensions and weight.